# Should I write a unit test to this?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

Given the following pseudocode:

```
List dohList = new List();
Foo foo   = A.getFoo();
if ( foo != null ) {
    Bar bar   = foo.getBar();
    if ( bar != null ) {
        FooBar fb = bar.getFooBar();
            if(fb != null) {
                dohList = fb.fillList();
            }
    }
}

return dohList;
```

The whole point of the algorithm is to fill the list with elements or else return an empty list.

Should I write unit tests for the "intermediary" null checks or should I just mock the objects inside the unit tests concerning this specific method and all is good?

Comment: If you're working in a language that has first-class functions, you can define a function that stitches together functions with this logic included for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should unit test all of the branches of your function, especially one like this where it is easy to do so.

(though I might also recommend refactoring this code, as it violates the spirit, if not the letter of the Law of Demeter)